# How to forward by recipient in an exim relay?

Tags: linux, centos, email, exim

I've set up an Exim relay and i need to forward emails coming in for a particular domain to be sent to another address, but i'm having no luck so far.

I've set up a router like this:

```
postmaster_redirect:
  driver = redirect
  domains = domain.toredirect.com
  data = something@otherdomain.com
```

This in theory should do the trick of redirecting all mails sent to that domain to something@otherdomain.com but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there anything else i could try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Address rewriting](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html) (after `begin rewrite` directive). 
Try:

```
*@domain.toredirect.com something@otherdomain.com STt
```